# How to lag by an integer variable using R?

Tags: r, time-series, analytics, categories, lag

Say I have the following historical league results:

```
Season <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
Team <- c("Diverpool","Deverton","Diverpool","Deverton","Diverpool","Deverton","Diverpool","Deverton","Diverpool","Deverton")
End.Rank <- c(8,17,4,15,3,6,4,16,3,17)
PLRank <- cbind(Season,Team,End.Rank)
```

I want to (efficiently) create a one year lagged variable for each team based on two criteria:

1. lag `End.Rank` by `Season` (i.e. t-1 with `Season` as the time variable)
2. separate by team (Deverton's lagged `End.Rank` vs. Diverpool's lagged `End.Rank`)

Essentially, I'd like the output to be as follows:

```
l.End.Rank <- c(NA,NA,8,17,4,15,3,6,4,16)
```

Tried `lag()`, and lost when trying to do it in a `for()` loop at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the following...

Note that I've used a `data.frame` instead of the `matrix` you get with `cbind`:

```
PLRank <- data.frame(Season, Team, End.Rank)
```

With "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(PLRank)[, l.End.Rank := shift(End.Rank), by = .(Team)][]
#     Season      Team End.Rank l.End.Rank
#  1:      1 Diverpool        8         NA
#  2:      1  Deverton       17         NA
#  3:      2 Diverpool        4          8
#  4:      2  Deverton       15         17
#  5:      3 Diverpool        3          4
#  6:      3  Deverton        6         15
#  7:      4 Diverpool        4          3
#  8:      4  Deverton       16          6
#  9:      5 Diverpool        3          4
# 10:      5  Deverton       17         16
```

Or, with "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
PLRank %>%
  group_by(Team) %>%
  mutate(l.End.Rank = lag(End.Rank))
# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# Groups: Team [2]
# 
#    Season      Team End.Rank l.End.Rank
#     (dbl)    (fctr)    (dbl)      (dbl)
# 1       1 Diverpool        8         NA
# 2       1  Deverton       17         NA
# 3       2 Diverpool        4          8
# 4       2  Deverton       15         17
# 5       3 Diverpool        3          4
# 6       3  Deverton        6         15
# 7       4 Diverpool        4          3
# 8       4  Deverton       16          6
# 9       5 Diverpool        3          4
# 10      5  Deverton       17         16
```

---

***Update***

I had honestly entirely misread that you wanted this grouped by Season.

If you are lagging by season, perhaps you should consider widening the data, so that each season has just one row. Then a lag by season would be easy.

Examples:

Here, we use `dcast` from "data.table" to spread the values of "End.Rank" out by "Team". Then, we lag just the newly created columns.

```
library(data.table)
teams <- as.character(unique(PLRank$Team))
dcast(as.data.table(PLRank), Season ~ Team, value.var = "End.Rank")[
  , (teams) := lapply(.SD, shift), .SDcols = teams][]
#    Season Deverton Diverpool
# 1:      1       NA        NA
# 2:      2       17         8
# 3:      3       15         4
# 4:      4        6         3
# 5:      5       16         4
```

Or, if you wanted both the team names and the values to be in a wide form, you could try something like:

```
dcast(as.data.table(PLRank)[, ind := sequence(.N), by = Season], 
      Season ~ ind, value.var = c("Team", "End.Rank"))[
        , c("End.Rank_1", "End.Rank_2") := lapply(.SD, shift), 
        .SDcols = c("End.Rank_1", "End.Rank_2")][]
#    Season    Team_1   Team_2 End.Rank_1 End.Rank_2
# 1:      1 Diverpool Deverton         NA         NA
# 2:      2 Diverpool Deverton          8         17
# 3:      3 Diverpool Deverton          4         15
# 4:      4 Diverpool Deverton          3          6
# 5:      5 Diverpool Deverton          4         16
```

The approach in "dplyr" is similar. Since you're going to a wide form, you also need "tidyr" to be loaded.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
PLRank %>%
  spread(Team, End.Rank) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(lag), -Season)
#   Season Deverton Diverpool
# 1      1       NA        NA
# 2      2       17         8
# 3      3       15         4
# 4      4        6         3
# 5      5       16         4
```

Comment: Thanks!  Quick question on your `dpylr` answer: how does the code know to lag by season?

Comment: @MattBarger, Happy New Year! Please see my update and let me know if it's any more useful for you.

Comment: Thank you Ananda.  I have other variables so I'd like to keep the data in one column.  I assume I can `spread()`, lag, and then `gather()` for the same effect though, right?

Comment: @MattBarger, `spread` doesn't let you spread multiple columns at once. If your data are already sorted, and if you only have two values per "Season", then it should be a simple: `PLRank %>% mutate(End.Rank = lag(End.Rank, 2))`. Does that help?